# How can I use my own api to other platforms?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, cross-platform

I made a json api with using this => https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

All the articles I read teach the creation and use of api within its own platform, what I need is what I produce on the web, use it to in other platforms. I made my api but no idea about how to import it in other platforms..
**so how can I use my own api in my c# windows form application or my flutter project**

Any link, guide etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be clear about why you need an api.  If you need to transfer data from one system to another, pick a way that you know you can operate on both sides.
JSON or XML are just ways of representing data, first think about what you need and how can you transport that data between systems...After that the implementation should be clear.